# Store cell value of first few characters

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to change the name of a sheet according to the value of a cell.

here is the code I am using.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('file_name.xlsx') 
ws = wb['Sheet 1']
sheet_name = ws['B2']
ws.title = f'Marketing {sheet_name}'
```

This code works, but
my problem is I only need to extract the first 3 characters from the cell ws['B2'].
How can I do that.

Answer (score 3):

Use slicing:

```
sheet_name = ws['B2'].value[:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the characters in the string.

Edit the parameters to get the desired result.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('file_name.xlsx') 
ws = wb['Sheet 1']
sheet_name = ws['B2'].value
ws.title = f'Marketing {sheet_name[0:3]}'  # First character to third
```

Start reading the tabs by number so you don't have to change the tab name in the future.

Final code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('file_name.xlsx') 
ws = wb.worksheets[0] # First tab
sheet_name = ws['B2'].value
ws.title = f'Marketing {sheet_name[0:3]}' # First character to third
```